# Why does the accuracy get stuck at a constant value when using Keras for multiclass singles-label classification problem?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multiclass-classification

I am trying to solve a multiclass classification problem using Keras. The current network looks as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, time_major=False,return_sequences=False, return_state=False))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The accuracy value doesn't go beyond 0.3.

I have tried to change the value of the learning rate, use a more complex or simplest network, change the activation function of the last layer to sigmoid...

The results I obtained are:

```
Epoch 2/1000
80/80 [==============================] - 2s 30ms/step - loss: 1.3860 - accuracy: 0.3675 - val_loss: 1.3859 - val_accuracy: 0.3641
Epoch 3/1000
80/80 [==============================] - 3s 32ms/step - loss: 1.3858 - accuracy: 0.3675 - val_loss: 1.3857 - val_accuracy: 0.3641
Epoch 4/1000
80/80 [==============================] - 2s 30ms/step - loss: 1.3856 - accuracy: 0.3675 - val_loss: 1.3855 - val_accuracy: 0.3641
Epoch 5/1000
80/80 [==============================] - 2s 31ms/step - loss: 1.3854 - accuracy: 0.3675 - val_loss: 1.3853 - val_accuracy: 0.3641
Epoch 6/1000
80/80 [==============================] - 2s 30ms/step - loss: 1.3852 - accuracy: 0.3675 - val_loss: 1.3851 - val_accuracy: 0.3641
```

I have used 80% of the data for training and 20% for validation and have a total of 20.000 cases.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, the problem is that the loss is not decreasing, maybe the model is not complex enough or use a different optimizer.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your data. Does 80/80 mean you have only 80 samples? It looks like you're expecting the model to perform well after 6 iterations

Comment: I have a data set of 20.000 cases. And I only posted the results of the first 6 epochs to keep it simple here, but I obtain the same result after 2000 epochs. I have already tried with different optimizers such as RMSprop, Adam, SGD, etc. I'll keep trying.